# AppleScript error 1719

Tags: applescript

I've a problem with this applescript.  Error 1719.
[Instruments app](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH26-SW1)
I need to set the new slider value to 2.

This is my code:

```
tell application "Instruments"
    activate
end tell

activate application "Instruments"

tell application "System Events"

    tell process "Instruments"

        keystroke "," using command down --Instruments menubar -> Preferences

        tell window 1
            click button "CPUs" of toolbar 1

            set value of slider 1 of group 1 to 2

        end tell        
    end tell    
end tell
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z481x.png)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a reference error.

The slider is in `group 1 of group 1`. When using GUI scripting it's also recommended to wait for particular UI elements in case there are time-critical changes.

```
activate application "Instruments"

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Instruments"
        keystroke "," using command down --Instruments menubar -> Preferences
        tell window 1
            click button "CPUs" of toolbar 1
            tell group 1 of group 1
                repeat until exists slider 1
                    delay 0.2
                end repeat
                set value of slider 1 to 2
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!!